# How to make corners of openlayers with OSM map rounded?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, style

I'm trying to apply style with border-radius:XXpx to my openlayers map:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map(name)
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM())
```

But rounded corners are hidden by tiles of the map:
[screenshot](http://d2.files.namba.kg/files/58925431)

Is there any way to resolve this?

**UPD:**

There are following styles applied to my div:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

styles:

```
#map {
    border: solid 1px red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And overflow:hidden does not help

**UPD 2**

I can't make this code to work in Chrome (several versions)

Comment: I think this might be a better fit on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mozilla / Safari / IE

```
#map {
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Chrome

```
#map {
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#map div canvas{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm developing an app with electron (chromium) and I had to use the `#map div canvas` css. Did not include the `#map`, and it worked. I'm not sure I understand why. An explanation would be super helpful. Cheers.

Comment: Its just how css selectors work. Only “canvas“ would work too, but then you might apply the style to other parts of the page you didnt want to. If there is only one canvas element you are fine !

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add both border-radius and **overflow:hidden** to your div element.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that overflow:hidden doesn't solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I found answer [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13810600/599890).

**Short**: This is a bug/feature of Chrome, in other browsers border-radius + overflow:hidden works nicely.

**In detail** (copypasted from Stackoverflow):

> After reading the comment on Chrome I tried to get it working with
>   Chrome but that does not seem to be possible after reading
>   [border-radius in Chrome bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705249/css-border-radius-not-trimming-image-on-webkit) and [CSS Border radius not trimming
>   image on Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705249/css-border-radius-not-trimming-image-on-webkit) and using chromes dev tools to modify the element
>   styles.